# Contour plotting opengl(Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 (on Android) to draw simple 3D Contour lines. I have longitude, latitude and elevation values.

I would like to draw contours in 3d view in android.

Can you provide some sample code or point me in right direction where I can find more information on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Android opengl plot open source at Software Informer, you can also download

http://softwaretopic.informer.com/android-opengl-plot-open-source/

Choose the FILE | OPEN command to load:

3dfield interface
    - scattered (X,Y,Z) data points (up to a few million for registered version);
    - scattered (X,Y,Z, links) data points with links;
    - math function plot;
    - *.SHP files (ArcView ESRI Shapefiles);

Answer (score 0):

I don´t clearly understand what you need, but at least I´ve came across the following article:

*Android Lesson Eight: An Introduction to Index Buffer Objects (IBOs)*
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-eight-an-introduction-to-index-buffer-objects-ibos/